# Using Protected Custom Setting in Flows in 2GP Managed Package

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, second-generation-packaging

I created a 2GP managed package that includes a protected hierarchy custom setting (let's say it is called namespaced__Protected_Custom_Setting__c) for some configuration that needs to be hidden from the end user. I packaged a permission set that has this custom setting enabled.

However when I install the package in a developer org and try to use a flow that has that custom setting I am receiving unhandled fault. When I check the logs I can see the below error.

```
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR  common.exception.ApiQueryException: sObject type 'namespaced__Protected_Custom_Setting__c' is not supported. 
If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I know protected custom settings are working fine in a 1GP managed package but I cannot see if there is a limitation regarding to this in 2GP managed package. And I cannot give OLS/FLS as this is hierarchy custom setting. Also setting the flow in System Mode does not resolve the problem.

**How can I have protected custom setting in flow in a 2GP managed package?** Is this a known limitation? I can do a workaround and use invocable Apex since it looks like Apex can retrieve and/or modify the custom setting but I would prefer to keep it in the flow if possible.